# How can i change the background color or apply an color to an Item in Drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i am having a drop down list with some items now while checking the items from the list and if that item exists in the drop down i would like to apply color for that particular item.

Assume i have my drop down as follows

```
    123
    1234
    12345
```

Now if i found `123` i would like to apply color for that particular element any help please

Comment: Can you elaborate and post the code that you have written

Comment: It's impossible to add specific background colors to a basic `select` tag per element of the drop down. You'd have to make a drop down like control out of divs with some events to achieve that level of customizability.

Comment: @Tejs: You can specify background for options, but it's only supported in some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried a sample i don't know whether it works for your or not this is just a sample try as per your requirement

```
lst=new ListItem("123");
if (DropDownList1.Items.Contains(lst))
{
   for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
   {
     if (DropDownList1.Items[i].Equals(lst))
     {
        DropDownList1.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");
    }
  }
}
```

As per your second requirement

```
ListItemCollection lstr = new ListItemCollection();
lstr.Add("123");
lstr .Add("1234");
foreach (ListItem lst in lstr)
{
if (DropDownList1.Items.Contains(lst))
{
for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
  if (DropDownList1.Items[i].Equals(lst))
  {
    DropDownList1.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: red;");
  }
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah define a `List<string>` or an `ArrayList` to hold multiple values and then loop the statement using `foreach(listitem li in arr)` some thing like that will do the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot `User` it works fine for me on every browser i tested

Answer (score 0):

this isn't a direct asnwer but I would think you could use the following methods to retrieve, modify, and recreate the attributes for the drop down list.

Have you tried accessing the iten's attribute collection. It contains the item's css class but it's not directly editable.

```
dropdown.Items[0].Attributes.CssStyle
```

You'll have to retrieve the collection, copy it, define a new css attribute, clear the old one and assign a new one.